# Js and Divs, (even <div> is difference)

Tags: javascript, html

I Have find a javascript code that works perfectly for showing a **DIV**.
but this code works only for showing one **div** for each page.
i want to include many DIVS for hiding and showing in the same page.

I was try to replace the **div id** and **show/hide span id** with a rundom php number for each include, but still is not working.

so how i have to do it?

the JS code:

```
var done = true,
    fading_div = document.getElementById('fading_div'),
    fade_in_button = document.getElementById('fade_in'),
    fade_out_button = document.getElementById('fade_out');

function function_opacity(opacity_value) {
    fading_div.style.opacity = opacity_value / 100;
    fading_div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity_value + ')';
}

function function_fade_out(opacity_value) {
    function_opacity(opacity_value);
    if (opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'none';
        done = true;
    }
}

function function_fade_in(opacity_value) {
    function_opacity(opacity_value);
    if (opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (opacity_value == 100) {
        done = true;
    }
}
// fade in button
fade_in_button.onclick = function () {
    if (done && fading_div.style.opacity !== '1') {
        done = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout((function (x) {
                return function () {
                    function_fade_in(x)
                };
            })(i), i * 10);
        }
    }
};
// fade out button
fade_out_button.onclick = function () {
    if (done && fading_div.style.opacity !== '0') {
        done = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout((function (x) {
                return function () {
                    function_fade_out(x)
                };
            })(100 - i), i * 10);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: If jQuery is an option, you may find that that and the jQueryUI additions do what you require for very little additional work.

Comment: ID is unique, so you will only ever reference one element by using it

Comment: As Adrian mentioned, [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) is definitely the way to go. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/vDVGy/) of how easy this would be, and the cross browser support makes it very much worth using.

Comment: @musefan thx this is working but can i have the same ID for hide and show? and can I make the div for default on hide mode?

Comment: @user2773673: [Still really simple](http://jsfiddle.net/vDVGy/1/). You can easily create that hml within a loop too (if you are using a technology that supports that, e.g PHP, ASP.Net...)

Comment: thx this is what i want, now my only problem if i can with hiding and showing with 1 link, and have this for default on hide.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/7nazv/), you can edit code based on your needs ;)

```
$(function() {
   $('.sub-nav li a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
       var category = $(this).data('cat');
       $('.'+category).addClass('active').siblings('div').removeClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, link to the question on SO.

Comment: no, this findle am going to use, [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vDVGy/1/)
My only problem if i can with hiding and showing with 1 link, and have this for default on hide.

Comment: You should still explain it. Your other answer contains a lot of HTML and CSS which is not useful.

Comment: Oh, you need accordion based script...ok ;)

Comment: Yes, but my other answer is based on media gallery, which work on the same principals, hide/show divs with navigation/category based. I can't put that code here in that form...I think.

Answer (score 0):

finaly i found my self:

```
<a class="showhide">AAA</a>
<div>show me / hide me</div>
<a class="showhide">BBB</a>
<div>show me / hide me</div>
```

js

```
$('.showhide').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop navigation
});
$('div').hide();
```

Am just posting this in case someone was trying to answer.